# Add text to the beginning of a string before appending it to a file

Tags: linux, shell

I have the contents of a directory I want to turn into aliases. I want to append `alias`  to the front and `pwd` to the end to create a file of aliases:

```
echo 'alias'
ls >> ~/scripts/aliases.txt
echo '"command"'
```

The problem is that there are multiple results, and I want it done for every iteration.

So the contents of a directory looks like this:

```
foo bar
```

I want a file that says

```
alias foo "command"
alias bar "command"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
ls -1 |  tr -d '/' | sed  's/\(.*\)/alias \1 "command"/' > ~/scripts/aliases.txt
```

- `ls -1` list folder content each on new line
- `tr -d '/'` remove `/` for folder names
- `sed  's/\(.*\)/alias \1 "command"/'` replace each line with the same value (`\1`) with `alias` prefix and `"command"` suffix
- save the result to `~/scripts/aliases.txt` file